# Location without combadge

Tags: star-trek, communication

In DS9 'Dax' they cannot find the location of the kidnappers of Dax. However, during the episode 'The Nagus', Sisko requests Jake's location from the computer, and it's given.

In previous episodes, they cannot locate people after they removed their combadges. So, surely the computer looks for the combadge, and if it has been removed, then locates using sensors.

**So why didn't they do this in episodes which they were trying to find people who had removed their combadges?**

Comment: In some circumstances, the computer has no way of determining who you're looking for.  "Find the person who kidnapped John" is only possible if the computer finds John, or knows who took him in the first place.

Comment: In "The Nagus" Jake and Nog are in Cargo Bay Fourteen. Since this is not a public area, Jake has likely used his security clearance (gained while working with Miles O'Brien) to open the doors. The computer is presumably reporting his *last known location* rather than using sensors to find him.

Comment: Jake is a minor, so he's possibly lo jacked unlike an adult. As for Dax, they should have just scanned for Trill life signs. Considering there is just one

Comment: @Richard he hadnt worked with him yet

Comment: @Pioneer - Oh yeah, my bad. Which does beggar the question how he got into the cargo bay. Maybe he's got an "all access" pass that he's not supposed to use.

Comment: @Richard also, i don't believe this is a duplicate, because the linked with question does not explain why they sometimes using sensors and other times not.

Comment: @Pioneer - [Thaddeus' answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/24995/20774) seems to offer a number of possible reasons for this (the effort required, the need to avoid a "surveillance culture", etc)